# CodeIgniter: How to use the get() active record twice with previous active records?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, get

I have the following function under models as shown..

```
    public function get_products($category, $brand, $filter, $page, $limit) {
    // output
    $output = "";
    // offset
    $offset = $limit * ($page - 1);
    // query for pagination
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("products");
    $this->db->where("category", $category);
    if ($brand != "all") {
        $this->db->where("brand", $brand);
    }
    // first time use
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $total_rows = $query->num_rows();
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    switch ($filter) {
        case 'latest':
        $this->db->order_by("released", "ASC");
        break;
        case 'most-viewed':
        $this->db->order_by("views", "ASC");
        break;
        case 'price-low-to-high':
        $this->db->order_by("price", "DESC");
        break;
        case 'price-high-to-low':
        $this->db->order_by("price", "ASC");
        break;
    }
    //second time use
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Here I want to use the `select`, `from` and `where` with 2 `this->db->get()` as you can see but the query ends after running the first `get()`. So is there any way to do that? Or I've to write the active records twice?

**The reason I'm trying this is to get the `num_rows` before limiting for pagination `total_rows` config.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

```
public function get_products($category, $brand, $filter, $page, $limit) 
{
    $output = "";
    $offset = $limit * ($page - 1);

    $this->getQuery($category , $brand);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $total_rows = $query->num_rows();
    //Call the query again 
    $this->getQuery($category , $brand);
    /*  This time limit and order will be applied to the query */   
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);

    switch ($filter) {
        case 'latest':
        $this->db->order_by("released", "ASC");
        break;
        case 'most-viewed':
        $this->db->order_by("views", "ASC");
        break;
        case 'price-low-to-high':
        $this->db->order_by("price", "DESC");
        break;
        case 'price-high-to-low':
        $this->db->order_by("price", "ASC");
        break;
    }
    //Run query now
    $query2 = $this->db->get();
}
/* This will only generate the query and will not run it */
function getQuery($category , $brand){

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("products");
    $this->db->where("category", $category);
    if ($brand != "all") {
        $this->db->where("brand", $brand);
    }
}
```